# 2 problems in Xquery with similar XML files and XMLNS

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

I'ld enquire multiple xml with Basex (file1.xml, file2.xml,....) downloaded from  https://www.rna.gov.it/RegistroNazionaleTrasparenza/faces/pages/OpenDataAiuti.jspx
but I'm not able to write the query on single file because it starts with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<LISTA_AIUTI xmlns="http://www.rna.it/RNA_aiuto/schema">
    <AIUTO>
        <CAR>884</CAR>
```

Merging is harder form me!I'm a newsbie but I want to learn Xquery!!
If I cancel the xmlns row it works
If I upload files in Mysql DB I can but it's not fast solution
How can I do?

Comment: Declare the namespace in your XQuery code and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martin Honnen pointed out, you need to add default namespace declaration line at the top:

```
declare default element namespace "http://www.rna.it/RNA_aiuto/schema";
```